# Programmatically building Metadata Navigation with Friendly URLs

Tags: 2013, navigation, managed-metadata

I've been looking online at a bunch of MSDN examples of how to programmatically build and then set Metadata Navigation through feature recievers. The sample code MSDN gives you is as follows:

```
NavigationTermSet navTermSet = NavigationTermSet.GetAsResolvedByWeb(termSet, web,
            StandardNavigationProviderNames.GlobalNavigationTaxonomyProvider);

navTermSet.IsNavigationTermSet = true;
navTermSet.TargetUrlForChildTerms.Value = "~site/Pages/Topics/Topic.aspx";

NavigationTerm term1 = navTermSet.CreateTerm("Term 1", NavigationLinkType.SimpleLink);
term1.SimpleLinkUrl = "http://www.bing.com/";

NavigationTerm term2 = navTermSet.CreateTerm("Term 2", NavigationLinkType.FriendlyUrl);
NavigationTerm term2a = term2.CreateTerm("Term 2 A", NavigationLinkType.FriendlyUrl);
NavigationTerm term2b = term2.CreateTerm("Term 2 B", NavigationLinkType.FriendlyUrl);

NavigationTerm term3 = navTermSet.CreateTerm("Term 3", NavigationLinkType.FriendlyUrl);
```

As a simple example. This is nice, however I can't fully comprehend how the `FriendlyUrl` terms work. For instance, how do I set a custom FriendlyURL path (such as `/community-blog`) for a term? How do I set the path the term should re-direct you to (such as `~site/blog/CustomHomePage.aspx`)? I want to utilize the friendly URL naming but can't figure it out from what's documented on MSDN. Has anyone figured it out? As a workaround, I'm currently creating all `SimpleLink`s and setting their `SimpleLinkUrl` property, but that doesn't let you set a custom friendly URL as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a bit of discovery, but I figured out that there are some values you can actually edit for `NavigationLinkType.FriendlyUrl`. Microsoft doesn't have any documentation that shows how you can edit them. Below is an example that will show better than I can explain:

```
NavigationTerm term = navigationTermSet.CreateTerm("Communities", NavigationLinkType.FriendlyUrl, Guid.NewGuid());
term.FriendlyUrlSegment.Value = "communities";
term.TargetUrl.Value = "~site/Communities/";
termStore.CommitAll();
```

The key here is that `FriendlyUrlSegment` and `TargetUrl` are `CustomizableString` types. I'm not sure what assembly defines that type, but you need to dig into the value property of a `CustomizableString` to be able to modify it. I had simply assumed that these were locked off because `term.FriendlyUrlSegment = "communities";` would not run.

There are a few caveats I've found with these properties:

- `FriendlyUrlSegment.Value` must *not* contain slashes (`/\`).
- `TargetUrl.Value` must lead to a web page. For instance, you cannot use `~site` to bring you to the home page of the site, although you can if you manually create a friendly navigation term through the Term Store Manager.
- `TargetUrl.Value` *must* lead to a page in the current site (`SPWeb`).
- You *can* reuse the same `NavigationTerm` item. If you were to take the first three lines of the code above and put them into a loop the `term` variable will always refer to a new term everytime you call `CreateTerm`.

Once that is all figured out though, you can deploy a nice, clean set of metadata navigation.